# How to detect Catalyst mode in react-native?

Tags: react-native, mac-catalyst

I'm using react-native 0.62.x

If react-native runs in Catalyst (system is macOS), `Platform.OS` would still be `iOS`. Is there any official way to detect `isCatalyst` ?

Answer (score 7):

I maintain react-native-device-info, and this was a problem until about 5 minutes ago ;-)

I just merged [a PR that adds "desktop" to the possible return values from `getDeviceType()`](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/pull/1137). Catalyst really is an iOS build, so Platform.OS as iOS is not incorrect, but now the combination of `iOS` platform and `desktop` as return value of `getDeviceType()` should unambiguously tell you it's running on a desktop machine via a catalyst build target.

It will be available in react-native-device-info 7.4.0 and higher

Cheers